# requestPermissions siempre rechazado (always denied)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-permissions

Ya llevo rato dándole vueltas a este problema: estoy haciendo una pequeña prueba de leer los archivos externos para comprobar la existencia de la carpeta /dev  y ponerlos en una lista. El funcionamiento está bien, me muestra los archivos; sin embargo, me causa ruido que cada que intento solcitar los permisos de WRITE_STORAGE_DATA y READ_STORAGE_DATA:

1.- No me muestra el dialogo en pantalla solicitandole al usuario que acepte los permisos, directamente me los solicita sin más
2.- Cuando solicita los permisos siempre los rechaza,

Archivo .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.iflytek.uart.UARTKit">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28"
        tools:node="replace"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android:name=android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android:name=android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.UARTAplicacion"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main Activity donde está la lista

```
package com.iflytek.uart.UARTKit;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.iflytek.aiui.uartkit.*;
import com.iflytek.aiui.uartkit.constant.UARTConstant;
import com.iflytek.aiui.uartkit.entity.MsgPacket;
import com.iflytek.aiui.uartkit.listener.EventListener;
import com.iflytek.aiui.uartkit.listener.UARTEvent;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "UART_MainActivity";
    public UARTAgent mAgent;
    private String mPath;

    private List<String> recentItem = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterItem;
    private int permissionsCount;
    private String pathname = "";
    private ListView lstOpciones;
    private TextView tv1;
    private Button btn1;
    private Button reqPermission_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String command = "chmod 777 /dev";
        try {
            System.out.println("INICIO - Runtime");
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", "su", "-c", command});
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Hubo un error al solicitar permisos de administrador");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
        lstOpciones = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Lv_1);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        reqPermission_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
        adapterItem = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itemList);
        lstOpciones.setAdapter(adapterItem);

        //    "/dev/ttyS2"
        Log.d(TAG, "Init UART Sstarts");
        /*
        SerialPortFinder finder = new SerialPortFinder();
        String[] path = finder.getAllDevicesPath();
        for (String s : path) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mPath)) {
                mPath = s;

            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Init UART --"+s);

        }
        */
        // Array TEXTO donde guardaremos los nombres de los ficheros

        lstOpciones.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Object o = lstOpciones.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        pathname += "/" + o.toString();
                        recentItem.add(o.toString());
                        System.out.println(pathname);
                        actualizarLista();
                    }
                }
        );
        reqPermission_btn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (checkPermission()) {
                            pathname = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                            Log.d(TAG,pathname);
                            actualizarLista();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Se negaron los permisos necesarios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        btn1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (recentItem != null) {
                            pathname = pathname.replaceAll(recentItem.get(recentItem.size()-1), "");
                            recentItem.remove(recentItem.size()-1);
                            actualizarLista();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );


        mAgent = UARTAgent.createAgent(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/dev/ttyS2", 115200, new EventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onEvent(UARTEvent event) {
                switch (event.eventType) {
                    case UARTConstant.EVENT_INIT_SUCCESS:
                        System.out.println("Init UART Success");
                        Log.d(TAG, "Init UART Success");
                        break;

                    case UARTConstant.EVENT_INIT_FAILED:
                        System.out.println("Init UART Failed");
                        Log.d(TAG, "Init UART Failed");
                        break;

                    case UARTConstant.EVENT_MSG:
                        MsgPacket recvPacket = (MsgPacket) event.data;
                        System.out.println("recvPacket" + recvPacket.toString());
                        //Log.d(TAG,"recvPacket " + recvPacket.toString());
                        //processPacket(recvPacket);


                        break;

                    case UARTConstant.EVENT_SEND_FAILED:

                        MsgPacket sendPacket = (MsgPacket) event.data;
                        mAgent.sendMessage(sendPacket);
                        //Log.d(TAG,"sendPacket " + sendPacket.toString());

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void actualizarLista() {
        itemList.clear();
        File f = new File(pathname);
        if(!f.isDirectory()) {
            return;
        }
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.println("Archivo de registro: " + file.getName());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    itemList.add(file.getName() + "/");
                } else {
                    itemList.add(file.getName());
                }
            }
            adapterItem.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (itemList.size() > 0) {
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Los ficheros están vacíos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        for (int i: grantResults){
            System.out.println("Permisos aceptados: "+i);
        }
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 2201:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Se aceptó el permiso de lectura",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"NO se aceptó el permiso de lectura",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            case 2202:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 &&
                        grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Se aceptó el permiso de escritura",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"NO se aceptó el permiso de escritura",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
    public boolean checkPermission() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int permisoLectura = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int permisoEscritura = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if ((permisoEscritura == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (permisoLectura == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Los permisos ya habían sido concedidos");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permisos consedidos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "oermiso especial escritura", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    showExplanation("Permiso necesitado","Rationale escritura",Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,2202);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "oermiso normal escritura", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    requestPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,2202);
                }
                if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "oermiso especial lectura", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    showExplanation("Permiso necesitado","Rationale lectura",Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,2201);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "oermiso normal lectura", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    requestPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,2201);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void showExplanation(String title,
                                 String message,
                                 final String permission,
                                 final int permissionRequestCode) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        requestPermission(permission, permissionRequestCode);
                    }
                });
        builder.create().show();
    }

    private void requestPermission(String permissionName, int permissionRequestCode) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{permissionName}, permissionRequestCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Los permisos son: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` y `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, actualmente solo necesitas pedir el primero `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. No necesitas definir `ACCESS_SUPERUSER`, ya que este permiso es obsoleto, elimínalo.

Con respecto a los comentarios:

> "1.- No me muestra el diálogo en pantalla solicitandole al usuario que
> acepte los permisos, directamente me los solicita sin más, 2.- Cuando
> solicita los permisos, siempre los rechaza"

El usuario puede indicar que no quiere le sea mostrado el diálogo, por esta razón seguramente ya no se vuelve a mostrar, puedes eliminar el caché de la app o reinstalarla para que vuelva a pedir el permiso.

Algo muy importante el usuario decide si acepta o no los permisos, **actualmente las políticas de las aplicaciones no permiten que le sea asignado un permiso sin el consentimiento del usuario.**

Comment: ok ya eliminé el permiso de READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE del manifiesto y el MainActivity, también elimné el ACCESS_SUPERUSER del manifiesto. Igual reinstallé la aplicación pero sigue sin preguntarle al usuario si acepta o no el permiso, el código automáticamente hace la solicitud de permiso al sistema y este lo niega en todos los casos